# Angular2 addArticle is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, import, angular2-moment

When clicked on the submit button, I encounter this msg in the console and also if someone can help me how to import the moment from node_modules to angula2 project!!

My app.component.html

```
<form class="ui large form segment">
  <h3 class="ui header">Add a Link</h3>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title" #newtitle>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="link">Link:</label>
    <input name="link" #newlink>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button (click) ="addArticle(newtitle, newlink)" class="ui positive button">Submit link</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

My app.module.ts

```
export class AppModule { 
  addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link:HTMLInputElement): boolean{ 
    console.log('title: ${title.value} and link: ${link.value}'); 
    return false; 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Please post code here

Comment: Can you access the above link please, everything is mentioned in that link is in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the addArticle method in app.module.ts you should put that in app.component.ts

```
export class AppModule { 
  addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link:HTMLInputElement): boolean{ 
    console.log('title: ${title.value} and link: ${link.value}'); 
    return false; 
  } 
 }
```

move the addArticle method to app.component.ts as you're using that in app.component.html

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Okay, proceed .!';
  names = [];
 // myDate = Date;

  constructor(){
    this.names = ['Tuan','Mark','Kevin'];
  //  this.myDate = new Date();
  }
 addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link:HTMLInputElement): boolean{ 
        console.log('title: ${title.value} and link: ${link.value}'); 
        return false; 
      } 
}
```

For moment  use the below import

```
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment/module';
```

after `npm install angular2-moment`..  http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular2-moment

Comment: I did write that in appcomponent

Comment: Yes, and also see the HTML please https://github.com/madurimanoj/ng-book2/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: i have seen the whole code and you should write that method in app.component.ts